# How to create angular component dynamically and append to top instead of bottom?

Tags: angular

I am able to create component using ComponentFactoryResolver and . However, it appends my component to the bottom, how would I append it so the newest component is on top?

```
const compFactory = this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.componentClass);
this.comp = this.containers.createComponent(compFactory);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer and its really simple, createComponent takes an index so you just pass in zero to prepend

```
const compFactory = this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.componentClass);
this.comp = this.containers.createComponent(compFactory, 0);
```